# Capacitance of convoluted circuit

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

[image]

What is the capacitance of this circuit if S is closed? AFAICS, Rules for capacitors in series or parallel can only help to simplify the problem down to

```
     |--||--|
A -- |      |------|--- B
     |--||--|--||--|
```

, but this weird parallelism with nothing for the third capacitor is what confuses me.

Comment: C5 and C4 in parallel, and are in series with C1 and C3. (C2 and C6 are shorted, so do nothing)

Comment: As @Icy says/implies, C2 and C6 can have no current through them because they are shorted out. Throw 'em away and what are you left with.

Comment: @Icy "(C2 and C6 are shorted, so do nothing)" That's what I anticipated! Can you make that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Switch S1 closed, circuit reduces to:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqVCNO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>